# Passing data from parent ViewController to child UITableViewController via Object

Tags: ios, swift

I have a couple of delegates that work in my code already (not asking how to use them). I'm having a problem getting data from the parent ViewController (`More Information` in the storyboard belongs to class `InputViewController`) to the child TableViewController (`AddressTableViewController`) as I'm unable to reference the parent controller from this class.

Both TableViewControllers and the map are in `InputViewController`. I want to send data (the reverse-geolocated address from locationManager) from the map to `AddressTableViewController` to fill in the cell text. The TableViewControllers are tied to the `InputViewController` (main controller) via an Object (selected in the object library).

[image: Storyboard]
Code: https://gist.github.com/damionjn/c148a07a39b5c27e7f78

You'll see I'm trying to use the protocol at the bottom of `InputViewController` here: 
https://gist.github.com/damionjn/c148a07a39b5c27e7f78#file-gistfile1-swift-L125
But I'm unable to use it as I have no access to `InputViewController`, thus `mapAddressDataSource` is always `nil`. I've tried creating an instance of it in `AddressTableViewController`'s `init()` and creating an IBOutlet without any luck.

[image]

Comment: Who is implement the delegate MapAddressDataSource (you should rename this to MapAddressDelegate)

Comment: It's not clear whether you're using the words parent and child correctly. Did you add a container view (or 2) to InputViewController, and the table view controllers are the embedded controllers? It looks more like you have one controller with a map view and 2 table views as subviews.

Comment: Sorry the names are kind of mixed up. More Information controller in the storyboard's class is `InputViewController` and yes, both table views are inside of it, but I have their `dataSource` being delegated out to their own tableViewControllers via an Object. So I guess to clear things up: the objects are children of the view controller, not the tableViewController itself. And the table views themselves are children of the controller as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having a problem getting data from the parent ViewController (More Information in the storyboard belongs to class InputViewController) to the child TableViewController (AddressTableViewController) **as I'm unable to reference the parent controller from this class.**

Why not?

Create a property on `AddressTableViewController` for your `InputViewController` but create it as weak and you can access it without causing any problems (retain cycles).

e.g.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) InputViewController *parentInputViewcontroller;
```

Then you should be able to access any of the data on `self.parentInputViewController` from within your tableView subclass.

Comment: Also, make sure you: tableView.parentInputViewController = self from within your parent controller.

Comment: This works, thank you. 
I tried this already and wasn't sure if you could do it, but I named it `inputViewController` which was interfering with another property even though I don't have one already named that? I was getting the error `Cannot override strong property with weak property`